# After trashing com.apple.safari in Mavericks is there something else I can try to reset Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, preferences, library

I have unfortunately picked up a piece of malware that overwrote my Safari homepage and "open new window with" setting in Mavericks. I just reinstalled to a backup image so the malware is gone, but left me with an open question.

In previous OS X versions, I would be able to delete all the Safari-related folders and `com.apple.safari.plist`-like files under `~/Library` and `~/Library/Preferences` and that would reset Safari to a minty fresh state. That no longer seems to be the case.

Even though I delete every single file related to Safari in my user library folder, if I set the homepage to google, and delete all those files, it stays as google - a.k.a. does not revert back to Safari's default `http://www.apple.com/startpage/`

Is there some other 'hidden' place Mavericks stores its settings for Safari?

Comment: Did you try Reset Safari under Safari Menu ?

Comment: Yep - that doesn't "reset" Safari, so it's a bit misleading, it's more of a "clear data".

Comment: Did you remove the folder ~/Library/Safari ?  Can you create a new user and see if the problem is there too?

Comment: If you create a new user - then Safari does reset. So it seems like Mavericks does store the Safari settings somewhere in the user folder, but can't figure out where.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to ask a question, but sometimes deleting "everything in Safari" isn't sufficient. Malware of this type installs files in a variety of folders. Examples include the LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons, PrivilegedHelperTools, and Extensions folder. You need to [identify the malware](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-identification/) first, and then [follow instructions](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg/) on where to look, and what to delete. Resetting Safari isn't sufficient when files located outside the "scope" of Safari (for lack of a better term) and spawning processes to be used by Safari.

Comment: Thanks njboot but my question wasn't really about dealing with the malware, it was about how to reset Safari. The malware bit was just how I stumbled onto the behavior in the first place.